# Unable to locate NamespaceHandler for namespace http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey

Tags: java, xml, web-services, xsd, mule

I might be really off on this one but can anyone look over this configuration and tell me why I am seeing this problem when tomcat 7 starts? I am using mule 3.3 but that you can see from the headers below.

```
Unable to locate NamespaceHandler for namespace [http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey]
```

This is the header of my mule configuration file:

```
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns:jersey="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd  
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.3/mule.xsd  
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/3.3/mule-http.xsd  
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/3.3/mule-xml.xsd 
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jersey/3.0/mule-jersey.xsd
    http://jersey.apache.org/core http://jersey.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd">
```

And this is the content that uses the jersey tags:

```
<flow name="HelloWorld">
 <inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8081/helloworld"/>
     <jersey:resources>
         <component class="com.sample.helloworld.HelloRest"/>
     </jersey:resources>
</flow>
```

Comment: You miss JAR file in classpath that handles your `jersey` xml namespace in configuration file

Comment: I have added     <dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
  </dependency> to every pom.xml remotely related to the web service and I still get the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use maven, add following dependency to your POM:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-jersey</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I had the wrong dependency for jersey thanks you your snippet above tomcat just started correctly the service is failing but thats my problem :p thanks!